# How can I get a report of all MAC addresses nearby?

Tags: ip, mac-address

I am trying to get an idea of how to get a list of all the MAC/IP's near my network. I've tried arp -a commands (What I found from some previous searching.) but those are not showing any of the iPhones or iPads that I know are for sure in range. The goal is to get all available devices, not only ones that are already connected. I have zero programming or networking experience so please be as simple as you can with a response. This is for a business meeting I have coming up with some IT guys, and I would like to have a general idea of how this can work before I get there.

Comment: `1.` If a device isn't active on the network then you're not going to be able to get it's MAC address. `2.` You need to run an ARP/MAC scan on the network to get the MAC addresses of all of the active devices. Running something like this on a Windows machine would work- http://www.colasoft.com/mac_scanner/index.php?act=mac_scanner

Comment: If you have a Linux based firewall install [arpalert](http://www.arpalert.org/arpalert.html) or another package like that.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this, but my goto is nmap.

```
sudo nmap -sP -n 123.456.789.0/24
```

Also you can use `arp -an`

Comment: arp -an gave me similar results to the arp -a, as I would've guessed just by basic logic. Still trying to include iOS devices. 

The sudo command is just asking for a password, which I apparently don't know after trying all the passwords I believe to be relevant to my laptop and network, but I suppose the people who do this for a living will know these types of things for my specific case. I appreciate your input though. @GregoryPatmore

Comment: the sudo password will be your own password, if you're allowed admin rights on the machine it'll let you run stuff as root.

Comment: i usually do a broadcast ping anyhow, `ping 255.255.255.255 -b`

Comment: broadcast ping can work too.

Comment: @zshock: sudo would be to run the command as the root user. If you already are logged in as root user you can omit the sudo command.